# How to view Silverlight videos without Moonlight from Linux?

Tags: moonlight

Like as people can view flash videos under Linux with ex.:

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/
https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/87011
```

are there any similar solutions for Silverlight?

UPDATE: moonlight is not such a great solution because it has been deprecated AFAIK.

Comment: It should be noted that the script you are using as an example, doesn't do what you want. That script grabs the html5 compatible version of the video for sites and services that supply them, but doesn't actually play flash videos. It replaces the flash content with more compatible content already supplied by the site.

Comment: It's my personal opinion that anybody using Silverlight on their websites should be shot. I'm looking at you, University website for online class lecture videos. I can play videos with Moonlight, but its wonky. Installed Windows 8, and found the videos worked fine, but the navigation page for finding videos would not (could only watch those in the recents panel). Terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I used to use Netflix on my PC the best solution I had available was to run Windows XP inside of a virtual machine using VirtualBox.

The VirtualBox documentation actually does a fairly good job of explaining how to install and configure Windows in a newly-created VM:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#gui-createvm

Once the Windows VM is installed and you have Silverlight set up, you can get a movie playing, full-screen the browser window, then use your Linux window manager to display it however you want--fullscreen, managed, or floating. I used to set up like this so that I could watch a movie while working on personal projects.

I know this isn't exactly an alternative to Silverlight, but it does give you the opportunity to use Netflix without leaving your Linux OS which was the main requirement for me since I really do need Linux to be productive. It also gives me an opportunity to isolate Windows from my primary OS and to snapshot the Windows virtual disk in a known-good, virus-free state; any time something gets messed up in that OS, all I do is simply revert back to that good state and all is well.

Comment: I should also note that this solution is strongly dependent on the capability of your PC hardware. For example, I can run it on my dual-core, 4 GB RAM laptop but it's not exactly the best quality. I typically run setups like this on my quad-core 9 GB RAM desktop PC.

I wouldn't expect it to run very well on a single core machine or one with 1 GB or less of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Silverlight on Linux, AFAIK Moonlight is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Wine is an option as well if you want to go down that road.  You can then run the windows firefox under that and install silverlight.

If you are using Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

I have heard of a few people getting `netflix-desktop` to work on other distros though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you're looking for is here: http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/11/ppa-for-netflix-desktop-app.html
I've heard mixed reviews about netflix-desktop on a 64-bit kernel. It's unstable on 64-bit. It's much more stable on 32-bit. 
 If you need netflix on Linux it's either this or Virtualbox.